# Qmake - is there a "notcontains"?

Tags: qt, qmake

I know Qmake provides the contains function to check if a variable contains some value :

```
contains( CONFIG, PartialStatic ) {
   // my code here
}
```

Is there such a thing as a "notcontains" ?

```
notcontains( CONFIG, PartialStatic ) {
   // my code here
}
```

instead of having to do this :

```
contains( CONFIG, PartialStatic ) {
}
else {
   // my code here
}
```

I haven't seen anything like this mentioned in the Qt documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QMake does allow unary NOT operator:

```
! contains( CONFIG, PartialStatic ) {
  # not that
  message(Not that)
}
```

You can combine with boolean functions.

Comment: This also works with the `CONFIG` [test function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-test-function-reference.html). E.g. `! CONFIG(PartialStatic) { ... }`.